# Infimums of Poset of Unlabelled Subtrees

Tags: graph-theory, posets, trees

I will use $T$ to refer to the set of unlabelled, rooted trees, and use $(t,r)$ to denote a tree and its root. Let $(T, \preceq)$ be a poset where $(t_1,r_1) \preceq (t_2,r_2)$ means that $t_1$ is a subtree of $t_2$, with $r_1$ mapped to $r_2$.

I realize that $(T, \preceq)$ is not a meet semi-lattice, as shown in this counterexample:

[image: (0,1)(1,2)(1,3)(0,4)(4,5)(5,6), r1 = 0; (0,1)(1,2)(2,3)(2,4)(4,5), r2 = 0]

However, I have struggled to find an counterexample to a weaker condition. For any $t^2 = ((t_1,r_1),(t_2,r_2)) \in T^2$ consider the set $S_{t^2}$ of lower bounds $(t',r') \preceq (t_i,r_i), \forall (t_i,r_i) \in t^2$. Now let $\overline{S_{t^2}}$ be the subset of $S_{t^2}$ of elements $y$ such that $y \npreceq x \forall x \in S_{t^2} \setminus y$. My question is, $\forall t^2 \in T^2$, does $\overline{S_{t^2}}$ always have a meet? My initial thought was no, but after struggling for a while, I have been unable to make any progress.

Update: I did a computer search for the case of binary trees, and found the following counterexample:

```
        0____
       /     \
    __0       0__
   /         /   \
  0         0     0
 / \       /     / \
0   0     0     0   0


        ______0__
       /         \
    __0__         0
   /     \       / \
  0       0     0   0
 / \     / \
0   0   0   0
```

Comment: What is the quantifier for $i$?

Comment: I meant to imply $\forall i \in \{1,2\}$, I realize that could be clearer, whoops. I've edited now, although I feel it's still phrased in way that's unpleasant to read.